# Utilizar a quantidade de caracteres obtidas em um sentença da expressão regular na substituição de string

Tags: javascript, regex, parser, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Estou fazendo um parser Markdown, como parte de um estudo sobre expressões regulares, e gostaria de usar a quantidade de caracteres obtidas em um trecho da expressão, como base de substituição da string, por exemplo:

```
# Titulo
## Titulo
```

o primeiro título irá ser adicionado um H1 pois eu tenho somente um #, o segundo será adicionado um H2 pois eu tenho dois #.

E gostaria de usar a quantidade de caracteres do trecho que encontra os # da expressão regular, para substituir uma string, por exemplo:

```
markdown.replace(/(\#+) *(.+)/ig, "<h?>$2</h?>");
```

Onde o ? seria a quantidade de # encontrados pela expressão.

Meu texto esta um tanto confuso, mas esta foi a melhor forma que encontrei para explicar a situação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu encontrei uma solução simple, replace pode receber uma função, então eu posso fazer o que eu quiser, veja minha solução:

```
        markdown = markdown.replace(/(\#+) *(.+)/ig, function(exp, n1, n2){
            size = n1.length;
            return "<h"+size+">"+n2+"</h"+size+">";
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Podias usar algo como `'## Titulo'.match(/^(#*)\s?(\w+)/);`. Desse modo recebes tudo separadinho e só tens de contar a `.length` da parte com `#`. Não vejo contudo como podes fazer isso tudo numa linha só, mas algo assim já daria:

```
var parts = markdown.match(/(#*)\s?(\w+)/);
if (!parts) return '';
var heading = parts[1].length + 1;
var text = parts[2];
return ['<h', heading, '>', text, '</', heading, '>'].join('');
```

Um exemplo seria assim: http://jsfiddle.net/arfte7zf/